# followTo issue with higher resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this snippet to make an element "stop" at a certain point when scrolling.

```
$.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: pos
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#braille').followTo(865);
```

The problem is that if there's not enough space to scroll (in higher resolutions), it's not positioned correctly.

It's important that you watch these 2 videos to understand how it works.

**1920x1080:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjT8FKAKTxA
It's properly positioned.

**2775x1514:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqQXm8BsfYA
Here instead as you can see it's not in the right place because there's not enough space to scroll

Resolutions until about `1190px` height are ok, with higher resolutions there's this problem.

How can I solve this..? Can I set a followTo starting from the bottom of the page? Or set it in percentage? Or say "if height is > than 1190 just put that there"....

**[Here](http://luca-longobardi.com/index_prima.html)** is the live webpage. To see what I'm talking about just zoom out like 3 times the resolution of your browser and try to scroll the page. The braille image isn't positioned properly under the music staff and above the yellow paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can set `followTo` relative to the bottom of the page using `$(document).height() - pos`. The basic principle is:

```
$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()
```

To change the `followTo` to work relative to the bottom of the page:

```
if ($(document).height() - $window.height() - $window.scrollTop() < pos)
```

To use a percentage you could do the calculation:

```
var percentageDownPage = $window.scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 100;
if (percentageDownPage > pos) { /* your code*/ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :)
I tried the first solution (here's the snippet: http://pastebin.com/1DEWk4Q3) but nothing changed.. here you can see the page live with the code changed: http://luca-longobardi.com/index_prima2.html

Comment: I tried also the percentage solution but nothing seems to change..
http://pastebin.com/vKwhTkqW
Live: http://luca-longobardi.com/index_prima4.html

Comment: Did you subtract the window height? I've updated the first solution.

Comment: Ok now it's better. :) It places in the correct location. But I need it to scroll to that position.. now it appears there when you scroll.